# Ler um arquivo txt e adicionar a uma lista duplamente encadeada em java

Tags: java

Sou bem iniciante em programação e estou codificando esse programa para um trabalho de faculdade.

Preciso ler os dados de um arquivo txt com os seguintes campos (titulo, estilo, ator, produtora, sinopse, caminho) e inserir em uma lista duplamente encadeada com a chave por Titulo, já montei a lista

```
public class Filme {
    
    private String titulo;
    private String sinopse;
    private String produtora;
    private String atorPrincipal;
    private String estilo;
    private String caminhoDoArquivoDaCapa;

    private Filme antTitulo;
    private Filme antAtor;
    private Filme antEstilo;
    private Filme proxTitulo;
    private Filme proxAtor;
    private Filme proxEstilo;
    
    protected final String SEPARADOR = ";";

    public Filme (String titulo, String sinopse, String produtora, String atorPrincipal, String estilo,
            String caminhoDoArquivoDaCapa) {

        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.sinopse = sinopse;
        this.produtora = produtora;
        this.atorPrincipal = atorPrincipal;
        this.estilo = estilo;
        this.caminhoDoArquivoDaCapa = caminhoDoArquivoDaCapa;

        this.antTitulo = null;
        this.antAtor = null;
        this.antEstilo = null;
        this.proxTitulo = null;
        this.proxAtor = null;
        this.proxEstilo = null;
    }
    
    public Filme() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public String getSinopse() {
        return sinopse;
    }

    public void setSinopse(String sinopse) {
        this.sinopse = sinopse;
    }

    public String getProdutora() {
        return produtora;
    }

    public void setProdutora(String produtora) {
        this.produtora = produtora;
    }

    public String getAtorPrincipal() {
        return atorPrincipal;
    }

    public void setAtorPrincipal(String atorPrincipal) {
        this.atorPrincipal = atorPrincipal;
    }

    public String getEstilo() {
        return estilo;
    }

    public void setEstilo(String estilo) {
        this.estilo = estilo;
    }

    public String getCaminhoDoArquivoDaCapa() {
        return caminhoDoArquivoDaCapa;
    }

    public void setCaminhoDoArquivoDaCapa(String caminhoDoArquivoDaCapa) {
        this.caminhoDoArquivoDaCapa = caminhoDoArquivoDaCapa;
    }

    public Filme getAntTitulo() {
        return antTitulo;
    }

    public void setAntTitulo(Filme antTitulo) {
        this.antTitulo = antTitulo;
    }

    public Filme getAntAtor() {
        return antAtor;
    }

    public void setAntAtor(Filme antAtor) {
        this.antAtor = antAtor;
    }

    public Filme getAntEstilo() {
        return antEstilo;
    }

    public void setAntEstilo(Filme antEstilo) {
        this.antEstilo = antEstilo;
    }

    public Filme getProxTitulo() {
        return proxTitulo;
    }

    public void setProxTitulo(Filme proxTitulo) {
        this.proxTitulo = proxTitulo;
    }

    public Filme getProxAtor() {
        return proxAtor;
    }

    public void setProxAtor(Filme proxAtor) {
        this.proxAtor = proxAtor;
    }

    public Filme getProxEstilo() {
        return proxEstilo;
    }

    public void setProxEstilo(Filme proxEstilo) {
        this.proxEstilo = proxEstilo;
    }
}
```

```
public class Filmoteca {

    private Filme primeiroTitulo;
    private Filme primeiroAtor;
    private Filme primeiroEstilo;
    private Filme ultimoTitulo;
    private Filme ultimoAtor;
    private Filme ultimoEstilo;
    private Filme atual;

    public Filmoteca() {
        this.primeiroTitulo = null;
        this.primeiroAtor = null;
        this.primeiroEstilo = null;
        this.ultimoTitulo = null;
        this.ultimoAtor = null;
        this.ultimoEstilo = null;
        this.atual = null;
    }

    public Boolean estaVazio() {
        return (this.primeiroTitulo == null);

    }

    public void insereOrdenadoPorTitulo(Filme filme) {

        Filme aux, anterior;

        if (this.estaVazio()) {
            this.primeiroTitulo = this.ultimoTitulo = filme;
            return;
        }

        if (filme.getTitulo().compareTo(this.primeiroTitulo.getTitulo()) < 0) {
            filme.setProxTitulo(this.primeiroTitulo);
            this.primeiroTitulo.setAntTitulo(filme);
            this.primeiroTitulo = filme;
            return;
        }

        anterior = this.primeiroTitulo;
        for (aux = this.primeiroTitulo.getProxTitulo(); aux != null
                && filme.getTitulo().compareTo(aux.getTitulo()) > 0; aux = aux.getProxTitulo()) {
            anterior = aux;
        }

        anterior.setProxTitulo(filme);
        filme.setAntTitulo(anterior);
        filme.setProxTitulo(aux);

        if (filme.getProxTitulo() == null) {
            this.ultimoTitulo = filme;
        } else {
            aux.setAntTitulo(filme);
        }
    }

}
```

Não sei como fazer a leitura do arquivo pra inserir na lista. Alguém pode me ajudar, por favor?

Comment: Qual é o formato do arquivo? Separado por virgulas ou por ponto-e-vírgulas? Possui cabeçalho? Onde está a declaração da classe `Filme`?

Comment: O formato do arquivo é txt, é separado por ponto-e-vírgulas

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta e coloquei a declaração da classe Filme

Comment: os dados são gravados dessa forma no arquivo titulo;sinopse;produtora;atorPrincipal;estilo;caminhoDoArquivoDaCapa

Comment: Agradeço pelas informações, publiquei uma resposta. Veja se resolve seu problema!

Comment: vlw cara, ajudou muito, Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, vamos simular um arquivo, chamado *arquivo.txt*. Seu conteúdo será o seguinte:

```
T0;S0;P0;A0;E0;/P0
T1;S1;P1;A1;E1;/P1
T2;S2;P2;A2;E2;/P2
T3;S3;P3;A3;E3;/P3
T4;S4;P4;A4;E4;/P4
T5;S5;P5;A5;E5;/P5
```

Você pode fazer a leitura do arquivo da seguinte maneira:

```java
try (final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("arquivo.txt"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // Faça algo com a linha lida aqui
        System.out.println(line);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {}
```

Com a linha lida, você pode dividi-la pelo charactere `;` e criar um objeto `Filme` com os campos criados:

```java
try (final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("arquivo.txt"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        final String[] campos = line.split(Filme.SEPARADOR);
        final Filme filme = new Filme(campos[0], campos[1], campos[2], campos[3], campos[4], campos[5]);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {}
```

Por fim, crie uma lista encadeada vazia antes de ler o arquivo e, conforme a leitura vai sendo feita, atualize a lista:

```java
final Filmoteca filmoteca = new Filmoteca();

try (final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("arquivo.txt"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        final String[] campos = line.split(Filme.SEPARADOR);
        final Filme filme = new Filme(campos[0], campos[1], campos[2], campos[3], campos[4], campos[5]);
        filmoteca.insereOrdenadoPorTitulo(filme);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {}
```

As importações necessárias no topo do arquivo serão:

```java
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
```